# CV skeleton with forest package

Tags: forest

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{forest} baseline, for tree={anchor=center, align=center, l sep+=0em, s sep+=0em} myGP1/.style={
            GP1}
    [
        [$\sigma$ [C [f]] [V [u]]]
        [$\sigma$ [C [m]] [V [e]] [C[N]]]
    ]
    \end{forest}


\end{document}
```

Hi, I am trying to draw syllabifications (CV skeleton) using Forest Package (with GP1 style), How could I draw the trees without the two branches in the red box?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Separating the `forest`s?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{forest}
%\usepackage{tikz} % loaded by forest

\begin{document}


\begin{forest} baseline, for tree={anchor=center, align=center, l sep+=0em, s sep+=0em}
        [$\sigma$ [C [f]] [V [u]]]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest} baseline, for tree={anchor=center, align=center, l sep+=0em, s sep+=0em}
        [$\sigma$ [C [m]] [V [e]] [C[N]]]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

If you were trying to use the `GP1` style, you should first download it at https://github.com/sasozivanovic/forest-styles/blob/master/forest-GP1.sty and use it as in the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{forest-GP1}
%\usepackage{tikz} % loaded by forest

\begin{document}


\begin{forest} GP1, baseline, for tree={anchor=center, align=center, calign=center, l sep+=0em, s sep+=0.5em}
    [
        [$\sigma$ [C [f]] [V [u]]]
        [$\sigma$ [C [m]] [V [e]] [C[N]]]
    ]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Ah....I forgot including GP1.sty in the preamble. Thank you so much!

Comment: @mangotango You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the empty root without all the other formatting of the `GP1` style, you can just use `for root={phantom, for children={baseline}}`, which sets the root to be empty and redefines the baseline of the tree to be the baseline of the root's children. Below I created an `unrooted` style that does this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{forest}
% \usepackage{tikz} % you don't need to load this separately since it's loaded by forest

\begin{document}

\forestset{unrooted/.style={for root={phantom, for children={baseline}}}}

(e.g., example number) % to show vertical alignment
\begin{forest} for tree={anchor=center, align=center, l sep+=0em, s sep+=0em}, unrooted
    [
        [$\sigma$ [C [f]] [V [u]]]
        [$\sigma$ [C [m]] [V [e]] [C[N]]]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, if you want your branches to come to a point under the syllable nodes, you can use the `sn edges` style defined on p. 8 of the `forest` documentation. In that case, you would want to remove `anchor=center`.

Comment: This is another good answer. Thank you, Jason. I gave up using XeLaTeX because of its slow compiling speed.

Comment: @mangotango, You're right that `pst-asr` is painfully slow with XeLaTeX, but if you're switching to using `forest` for these kinds of representations, I don't think you'll find nearly as much of a difference in compilation speed.